# Azure app service plan stopped showing monitoring info

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

My app service plan stopped showing monitoring information. So I can't see "Http Server Errors and Requests" and "MemoryPercentage and CpuPercentage" anymore. Does anyone know why this could have happened and how to fix it? 
The problem occurs on the preview portal (portal.azure.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, a couple of hours ago, the monitoring started working again. So the problem is fixed now, but it would be better if I knew what was going on..

Comment: Experienced the same issue with "Function App".

Up until recently, the Azure's "Function App" showed logs in a window called "Monitor". However, now they are blank. Neither new or old logs from the tracewriter is shown.

Does anyone now why? Or how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Without the logs it is a little bit difficult.

Did you try the (old) management portal? Can you browse to the Storage account and to the blobs and thence to the logs folder under there? You can go to this from the old portal and also from Visual Studio Server Explorer. Once you get to the logs you will be able to get some clues as to what is happening.

OR try the Storage explorer from Cloudberry which has a free subscription, You can use this to browse to the logs folder in your storage container which holds the blobs and then examine the logs for any clues as to what is happening.

Comment: I had a look at the logs but they didn't tell me anything. But for some reason, a couple of hours ago, the monitoring started working again. So the problem is fixed now, but it would be better if I knew what was going on.. Thanks for the tip for looking at the logs